# Horizontal mousewheel slider with overflowed content and inner scrollbar

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, idangero

I'm making fullscreen slider using Swiper, where slide change controlled via mouse wheel. But in some slides, I have overflowed content. And when I try to scroll this content - the slide change to the next.

Is it possible to scroll to next slide only when I scrolled to the end of the slide content? Here is a demo https://codepen.io/olegburakov/pen/EdqeLW, I want to scroll to the bottom of the first slide via mouse wheel.

```
//js
var swiperOptions = {
  loop: false,
  speed: 1000,
  grabCursor: false,
  mousewheel: true,
};

var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", swiperOptions);

//css
.swiper-slide {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. It suits to scrollable blocks that has size smaller than slide size. Because if it has equal size(or almost equal) it will be hard to change slide via mouse wheel, because scrollable block will catch mouse wheel event. The idea is simple: just `stopPropagation`  of the event in scrollable block.

```
document.querySelector('.scrollable-content').addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/olegburakov/pen/vVoPBE

Even I found a solution to check if scroll ended, there is no demo, but here is a code:

```
  const scrollableBlock = document.querySelector('.scrollable-block');
     if ('onwheel' in document) {
        // IE9+, FF17+, Ch31+
        scrollableBlock.addEventListener('wheel', scrollOverflowBlock);
      } else if ('onmousewheel' in document) {
        // for old
        scrollableBlock.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrollOverflowBlock);
      }

  function scrollOverflowBlock(e) {
    const delta = e.deltaY || e.wheelDelta;

    //Scroll up
    if (delta < 0) {
      if (e.target.scrollTop !== 0) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Slider scroll stopped (top)');
      }
    }
    //Scroll down
    else {
      //http://qnimate.com/detecting-end-of-scrolling-in-html-element/
      if (e.target.offsetHeight + e.target.scrollTop !== e.target.scrollHeight) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('Slider scroll stopped (bottom)');
      }
    }
  }
```

Maybe it will be helpful someone, or maybe someone propose better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `direction={"horizontal"}` in swiper.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial solution, maybe it will help. Try adding this to your Swiper config

```
  mousewheel: {
      forceToAxis: true,
  }
```

It stops swiper from doing horizontal scrolling when the user scrolls vertically with trackpad or mouse wheel, which has the effect of restoring default behavior to the vertical scrolling. It works in the Codepen.

The downside is it doesn't matter if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the content or not.

If you can change a Swiper instance's configuration without re-initializing it, you might be able to add your own event handling to turn `forceToAxis` on/off based on whether the user has scrolled to the bottom of the current slide's content.

On a side note: it looks like Swiper is designed only with presentations / slideshows in mind. It doesn't look like they've thought about internal scrolling, in which case it might not be the right library for the job.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I add `forceToAxis: true`  the slide changing via mouse wheel stops worked at all. https://codepen.io/olegburakov/pen/EdqrXE 
Or I do something wrong?

Comment: The next step would be seeing if you can change `forceToAxis` dynamically after creating your swiper instance. I don't know if that's possible, but if it is, then you can add event listeners to detect when you change slides, and when you scroll slides. When you scroll to the bottom of a slide, turn off `forceToAxis`

Comment: Oh, now I understood. Thank you!